# Changing storage path before config is initialised but still using env()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Setting up a IIS server that is going to run Laravel. Need to set storage path to point to a network drive that is mapped to Z:

As I need this to be configurable, I would like to do this through `.env` file.

I tried setting it through `AppServiceProvider` using something like `$app->useStoragePath(config('app.storage_path'));`.

This did set the storage path to the required directory when `dump(storage_path())` is used. But, the issue is that the filesystem config is set before the `AppServiceProvider` changes the directory. So in the end `Storage::disk()` uses the default directory for storage.

What I then tried was putting the `$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE_PATH', storage_path()));` inside `bootstrap/app.php` file. Obviously this doesn't work as the `env()` function always returns `null` here. I realized that Laravel has not initialized the `\Dotenv\Dotenv` package so its not reading the `.env` file.

To fix this issue I added this code to `bootstrap/app.php` -

```
/**
 * Initializing dotenv here, because we need configurable storage path
 */
$dotEnv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . '\\..\\');
$dotEnv->load();
$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE_PATH', storage_path()));
```

This does work, but Im not sure if this is the best solution as Laravel probably initializes the `.env` again at some point. So I was wondering if this is a good solution? Or is there a better one?

Thanks for replies!

Comment: What happens when you set the APP_STORAGE_PATH as a system variable on the server?

Comment: @Ishmael Yes, it does work like that too! So, what I should do is leave the $app->useStoragePath... and not initialize the dotenv package right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with @Ishmael provided answer in the comments and I'm using the `System Environment Variable`'s to remove the need of loading the `.env` file on every request.

So Im just left with this in the `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE_PATH', storage_path()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `config/filesystems.php` like so:

```
// ...
'default' => 'network',
// ... 
'disks' => [
    'network' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => env('APP_STORAGE_PATH', storage_path('app')),
    ],
    //...other disk configs
],
```

And then you can just set `APP_STORAGE_PATH` in your `.env` to `Z://path/to/app/storage` or whatever you need it to be.

If you need to switch to a different disk you can do:

```
return Storage::disk('local')->get('a file.pdf');
```

Comment: If I use `php artisan config:cache` it would make env return null everytime no? + I dont ned it only for `Storage::disk`, I need it for the whole storage folder.

Comment: With the setup above when you get a file from doing `Storage::get('file.pdf')` it would look for a file in `Z://path/to/app/storage/file.pdf`. So it **is** changing the whole storage folder. The second part with `Storage::disk()` will allow you to access files outside the scope of your default storage location, which will need to be defined in your `config/filesystems.php` file.

Comment: Also `php artisan config:cache` just clears and re-caches the configuration...I'm not sure what you mean by your comment

Comment: But laravel would still look for cache in the storage folder that is inside the project, which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: About the config:cache comment, I wasnt thinking I guess, its just that env returns null if you would try using it directly while config is cached, but your code example is using it through the config/filesystem so its fine.

Comment: If you are going to use a network drive for cache doesn't that majorly impact the performance of the cache? Why do you need to move cache to the network? Generally I would say this is a bad idea unless under very unique circumstances